# Filter based on a list column using arrow and duckdb

Tags: r, apache-arrow, duckdb

I'm using the R arrow package to interact with a duckdb table that contains a list column. My goal is to filter on the list column before collecting the results into memory. Can this be accomplished on a virtual duckdb table?

**Example**

```
library(arrow, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# keep rows if the list column contains *any* of these values.
keep_any_vector <- c(1, 4, 7)

dd <- tibble(
  y = letters[1:5],
  list_col = list(c(2L, 3L), c(4L), c(6L), c(7L, 8L, 9L, 11L), c(1L, 4L, 5L))
) %>%
  to_duckdb()

# desired output, but the filtering should happen before the collect()
dd %>%
  collect() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(keep_any_vector %in% unlist(list_col)))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   y     list_col 
#>   <chr> <list>   
#> 1 b     <int [1]>
#> 2 d     <int [4]>
#> 3 e     <int [3]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with vectorized (evaluated rowwise) SQL functions, so you don't need `rowwise()`. If you look at [the DuckDB list function docs](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/nested) you'd think "oh I could just write `len(list_col && keep_any_vector) > 0`", but you'll discover that `&&`/`list_intersect()` is in the docs, but only because it's merged to be released, but not available yet. (So if you're reading this in the future, try that.)

But for now, [this GitHub commment](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/7936#issuecomment-1590591547) suggests a workaround: `list_filter(l1, (x) -> list_contains(l2, x))`. To insert `keep_any_vector`, we'll have to do a little string manipulation to generate the SQL we want, i.e. something like `(x) -> list_contains([1,4,7], x)`. Putting it together:

```r
library(tidyverse)

keep_any_vector <- c(1L, 4L, 7L)

dd <- tibble(
  y = letters[1:5],
  list_col = list(c(2L, 3L), c(4L), c(6L), c(7L, 8L, 9L, 11L), c(1L, 4L, 5L))
) %>%
  arrow::to_duckdb()

dd %>%
  filter(
    len(
      list_filter(
        list_col, 
        sql(glue::glue("(x) -> list_contains([{glue::glue_collapse(keep_any_vector, ',')}], x)"))
      )
    ) > 0L
  )
#> # Source:   SQL [3 x 2]
#> # Database: DuckDB 0.8.1 [root@Darwin 22.6.0:R 4.3.1/:memory:]
#>   y     list_col 
#>   <chr> <list>   
#> 1 b     <int [1]>
#> 2 d     <int [4]>
#> 3 e     <int [3]>
```